# Integral across circle for likelihood

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to calculate a likelihood function which requires me to integrate

$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \exp\left((-a\sqrt{(x-b)^2+(y-c)^2})\right)dxdy$

where $a$ is a constant scalar, and $b$ and $c$ are in $(0,1)$. Does anyone have an idea for how I could approach this? Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: I see that you are integrating across a circle..would integrating in polar coordinates work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: $u=x-b$, $v=y-c$ Your integral is$I=\int_{-c}^{1-c}\int_{-b}^{1-b}e^{-a\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}dudv=\int\int e^{-ar}rdrd\theta$ where the last integral has to be divided up into 8 pieces.  Each piece is defined by a triangle in the shifted square with a vertex at $(0,0)$ and the other vertices given by the 4 corners of the square and the points where the square sides cross the axes.

This assumes both b and c are in the interval $(0,1)$.  If either is outside, you can draw the square and determine the $(r,\theta)$ coordinates for each part.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct in assuming that b,c are in the interval 0,1.  I will add to the question.  Can you elaborate on how I divide the integral in to eight pieces? Thank you again for your time!

Comment: The origin (with the assumptions on b and c) is inside the square.  To get the 8 triangles, the origin will be a vertex for each.  The square can be divided into four rectangles by cutting along the axes.  The rectangles are defined by the axis pieces from the origin to the edge of the square and the sides of the square crossing the axes.   Each rectangle is cut into two triangles by a line from the origin to the corner of the square defining the rectangle.  I don't have sketch capability, but it would be easy to see if you draw a diagram with the square  and axes as described.